# Bloop VSCode extension won't stop opening even after uninstallation

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-extensions

I briefly tried out the Bloop extension in VSCode, and decided it wasn't for me. After uninstall, it continues to pop up in the navigation sidebar, whenever I complete an import of an npm module, like this: [image: here it pops up while importing]------------------------------ [image: while importing again]
I find this quite obnoxious, especially since the extension is fully uninstalled and disabled. Is there some root folder I can remove all details of Bloop from VSCode?